# running two django apps with SSL in same apache server

Tags: django, ssl, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have `apache2` installed in `ubuntu lucid` ,and have enabled `ssl` .Now I am running a `django` app (lets say `myapp1` )on it using `mod_wsgi`.
I have configured the `/etc/apache2/sites_enabled/ssl` file and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ssl` as below.

Now I can run my app using the url

```
https://127.0.0.1/myapp1
```

I need to run another django app (say `myapp2` )in the same server,and that also uses SSL.So,how should I configure it?Can somebody please help me?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/me/dev/python/django/myapp1

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp1 /home/me/dev/python/django/myapp1/myapp1.wsgi
    Alias /site_media/ /home/me/dev/python/django/myapp1/media/
    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp2 /home/me/dev/python/django/myapp2/myapp2.wsgi
```

You will need to resolve any conflict though if they can't share the same static media files. That is, have each have media in different locations and configure settings for each Django project appropriately.